# Validating input using scanf (check whether input is char or int)

Tags: char, int, scanf

I want input entered by the user should be between 0 and 100. And if he or she enters a negative number or a number greater than 100 or a character, the loop must be triggered. I am using a do-while loop to validate the input entered by the user. But if I enter a character, the do while loop is executed infinite times. Can anyone explain why is this happening! and how to check if user has has entered a char or an int?

CODE IS WRITTEN IN C. AND COMPILED USING GCC.

```
int num;
do
{
    printf("num :");
    scanf("%d", &num);
}
while(num<0 ||  num>=100);
```

Comment: "And if he or she enters a negative number or a number greater than 100 or a character, the loop must be triggered" You mean your loop should stop or start?

Comment: You need to clear the input buffer

Comment: @prudhvi yes the loop should start. but when i entered a character , the statement "num :" is getting printed infinitely

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz can u please elaborate ?

Comment: @prudhvi The loop should continue if the user gives an invalid input. i.e. The loop should only work if user enters a negative number or number greater than 100 or any character. It is working well in case of negative number and number greater than 100. But when i entered a character , the loop is executing infinitely

Comment: @Anonymous Alright! I got it. Let me look into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf()` is expecting a number if it finds invalid input(something that doesn't match the format provided) it will return leaving the input buffer as is, that means leaving this invalid input there, then the loop condition evaluates to true and `scanf()` tries to read a number again to find the same invalid input as before, this repeats forever.

cleaning the input buffer will fix this, you can clean it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cleanBuffer(){
    int n;
    while((n = getchar()) != EOF && n != '\n' );
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int num = -1;
    do
    {
        printf("num :");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        cleanBuffer(); //we clean the buffer here
    }
    while(num<0 ||  num>=100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can u please give some reference from where i can read more about input buffer ?